# How to get a string after the string I given?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm coding in shell(bash), my script like this:

```
ps aux | grep something
```

and the result is:

```
something sds fgdsg -name i_want_this_string sdaf gfdsg  dfgdf
```

I want to get the string "i_want_this_string", and the position of this string is not fixed, and it always followed by "-name" with space, so I can't use awk.

So how to get the string? thank you~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
echo "$x"|grep -oP '\-name\s\K\w[^ ]+'
i_want_this_string
```

where `"$x"` holds :`something sds fgdsg -name i_want_this_string sdaf gfdsg  dfgdf`

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ echo something sds fgdsg -name i_want_this_string sdaf gfdsg  dfgdf | awk '
/something/ {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i=="-name") {
        print $(i+1)
        exit
    }
}'
i_want_this_string
```

Comment: Or `ps aux | grep '/something/ {print $5}` for the output *as given*. However, given the potential difference in output format for `ps` among various OS's, your location of `-name` and handling of the next field is more robust.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OP did say _and the position of this string is not fixed, and it always followed by "-name"_ which I do find odd.

Answer (score 0):

or... using sed:

```
$ echo "something sds fgdsg -name i_want_this_string sdaf gfdsg  dfgdf" | sed 's/^.*name \(\S*\) .*$/\1/'
```

i_want_this_string

Answer (score 0):

```
cs-server@csserver-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:/$ ps_aux="something sds fgdsg -name i_want_this_string sdaf gfdsg  dfgdf"
cs-server@csserver-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:/$ echo $ps_aux
something sds fgdsg -name i_want_this_string sdaf gfdsg dfgdf
```

For this simple case of variable grep is not needed ofc, but since you are searching among a number of strings we should add grep to eliminate not related strings.
Sed will eat everything up until it finds "-name ". As far as I understand "-name" is not needed in the output, so eat it too.

```
cs-server@csserver-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:/$ echo $ps_aux | grep "\-name" | sed -e "s/.*-name //g"
i_want_this_string sdaf gfdsg dfgdf
```

Good, but need to cut out everything after the needed string. Let's use cut with delimeter being "space" and take the first cut of a string.

```
cs-server@csserver-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:/$ echo $ps_aux | grep "\-name" | sed -e "s/.*-name //g" | cut -f1 -d' '
i_want_this_string
cs-server@csserver-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:/$
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pure shell script (using *parameter expansion*) assuming there's no
   spaces in the `-name` option's argument:

   ```
   n=$(ps aux | grep something) 
   n="${n#*-name }"
   n="${n%% *}"
   echo "$n"
   ```
2. If there *might* be spaces, (i.e. `something sds fgdsg -name "i want this string" sdaf gfdsg  dfgdf`), this should
   work:

   ```
   set -- $(ps aux | grep something)
   while [ "$1" ] ; do
       if [ "$1" = "-name" ] ; then
           echo "$2"
           break 
       fi
       shift
   done
   ```